# How to show facet values on the front end in Hybris?

Tags: solr, sap-commerce-cloud

I have added a brand attribute of String type in the ProductModel through item.xml.
I need to create a facet for brand. I have two brands - Sony and Canon.
After creating the facet, I'm able to see "Shop by Brand" on the UI, but I'm not able to find Sony or Canon under it.

The impexes I used are:

```
    INSERT_UPDATE SolrIndexedProperty;solrIndexedType(identifier) [unique=true];name[unique=true];type(code);sortableType(code);currency[default=false];localized[default=false];multiValue[default=false];facet[default=true];facetType(code);facetSort(code);priority;visible;useForSpellchecking[default=false];useForAutocomplete[default=false];fieldValueProvider;valueProviderParameter;facetDisplayNameProvider;customFacetSortProvider;topValuesProvider;rangeSets(name)
   ;$solrIndexedType;brand;string;;;;;;Refine;Alpha;;true;true;true;springELValueProvider;


     INSERT_UPDATE SolrSearchQueryProperty; indexedProperty(name, solrIndexedType(identifier))[unique = true]; searchQueryTemplate(name, indexedType(identifier))[unique = true][default = DEFAULT:$solrIndexedType]; facet[default = true]; facetType(code); includeInResponse[default = true]; facetDisplayNameProvider;facetSortProvider;facetTopValuesProvider
                                 ; brand:$solrIndexedType                                        ;                                                                                                      ;                      ;          ;                                  ;
```

Can someone please point out what am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

To make brand attribute as to available as facet need to follow below steps:

- Index brand attribute to SOLR via value provider by creating
  SolrIndexedProperty and associating it with value provider
- After indexing ensure that data being sent to SOLR for corresposding products
- Next steps is to do facet settings in Bakcoffice (or this can also be done via solr.impex while creating SolrIndexedProperty header impex for custom brand attribute)
- Edit that attribute in Backoffice facet configuration and go to "Facet Settings" tab which will enable us to define facet for custom (brand) attribute, which can be used to filter results based on facet value in PLP or SLP. Make "Facet" to 'TRUE'
  Or this can be handle via impex by setting **facet[default=true]**
- Select facet type to be 'Single Select' or 'Multi Select' via **facetType(code)**
- Re-Index Solr and changes should get reflect upon Search or PLP